# Setting tag value to image button

Tags: android, tags, imagebutton

I'm trying to set a tag value to image buttons inside a loop. The problem is their values are all the same I need to set their value depending on the loop. Here is my code.

```
int n = 0;
Cursor c = db.getUserExercises(Integer.parseInt(id), musclegroup);
tag = c.getCount();
if(c.moveToFirst())
        {

do{
               update = new ImageButton(this);
                update.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updatebtn);
                update.setTag(n);
                update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        for(int i=0;i<tag;i++)
                        {
                            if(Integer.parseInt(((ImageButton)v).getTag().toString()) == i)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), update.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                     }
                    });
n++;
}while(c.moveToNext());
```

I intend to set their value starting from 0 to what ever the size of the cursor, but I'm getting the same value as the number of cursors on all image button.

Comment: you are not doing anything with the button, plus, n is never changed.

Comment: this is your full code ?

Comment: there is a toast in the onclick listener to check the value of their tags. getting same problem. i've edited my post, forgot to include increment inside the loop. it was there but still the same problem.

Comment: @ljpv14 : what is tag value ?

Comment: I updated my post. I included the initial value of the tag. It seems that all iamgebutton's tag are set to the size of the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

**you can set Tag of the ImageView as your requirement. Because it setTag() method take Object type argument
For eg.**

imageView.setTag(45);

when we get imageView.getTag() then we will get 45 value of the ImageView Tag value

Answer (score 0):

what is the point of this piece of code in onClick?

```
if(Integer.parseInt(((ImageButton)v).getTag().toString()) == i)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), update.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
```

don't you want to call only

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

in your onClick, without 'for' cycle and 'if' statement and with `v.getTag()` instead of update.getTag()?

Comment: I'm sorry to include that, but that will be used for future validations.

Comment: Well this fixed my problem. I'll accept it later, but still need to think of a way to use this to my next process. Thanks anyways!

Comment: check whether v.getTag().toString() in onClick returns proper tag

Comment: It did by removing the it inside the loop.

Comment: and is it working then? you call update.getTag() to show in toast and i think there will always be only one 'update' variable so getTag will return always the same value, won't it?

Comment: As you can see, the update image button is being created depending on the size of the cursor and to make it dynamic.

Comment: but when your while loop is over, ImageButton update contains the last initialized instance from the while loop. onClick is not called in while loop, so when you call update.getTag() in onClick, it will always return the same value(tag of the last initialized update instance). i think you need to call v.getTag() in onClick or use final ImageButton update = new ImageButton(this); in the while loop to get tag of clicked ImageButton in onClick. But I hope i understand your needs right. :-)

Comment: I got your point. How can I use the v.getTag() to edittexts and textviews?

Comment: getTag()/setTag() is method inherited from class View, and EditTexts and TextsViews are both extending View, so you can normally call getTag()/setTag() on them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21285/discussion-between-berak-and-ljpv14)